# Neville's Method for Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

What do the numbers mean in Neville's method? Neville's method performs interpolation of numbers of the previous values, but what do the numbers mean?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please make the question self-contained by adding relevant information on how Neville's method has been introduced to you.

Comment: @Dai: Maybe you can read the section here and see if clears things up: http://www.fing.edu.uy/if/cursos/fiscomp/extras/numrec/book/f3.pdf